# Webpack build - remove comments and duplicated "use strict" declarations

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

I decided to use Webpack in a plugin I'm writing in Typescript. I built it and this is the code generated was this:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // identity function for calling harmory imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };

/******/    // define getter function for harmory exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/            configurable: false,
/******/            enumerable: true,
/******/            get: getter
/******/        });
/******/    };

/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };

/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 4);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
"use strict";

[...]


/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

My app has 2 bundled versions, one of them minified. Actually, I got that working.
Being that said, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to generate a non minified bundled version without all of these `"/******/"` comments?
2. Is it possible to get rid of the module loader (webpackBootstrap) completely, keeping my own code only?
3. Is there an option to strip the `use strict` from the non minified bundle? And why is it duplicated?

My config:

```
const config = {};
config.module = {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
      'ng-annotate',
      'ts'
    ]
  }]
};
config.plugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(), 
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {unused: true, dead_code: true, warnings: false} // eslint-disable-line camelcase
  }),
  new UnminifiedWebpackPlugin()
];
config.output = {
  path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.pack),
  filename: '[name].min.js'
};
config.resolve = {
  extensions: [
    '',
    '.webpack.js',
    '.web.js',
    '.js',
    '.ts'
  ]
};
config.entry = {
  'foo': `./${conf.path.src('app/foo/index')}`,
};
config.ts = {
  configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
};
config.tslint = {
  configuration: require('../tslint.json')
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing some problem with duplicated `use strict` and other code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any solution. I just had to accept this as it is.